# Male alternatives to dressing up as a geisha in Kyoto

Tags: japan, clothing, activities, kyoto

In Kyoto, there are plenty of [maiko henshin](https://tictokyo.wordpress.com/2015/11/16/unique-experience-in-kyoto-maiko-makeover/) (or maiko makeover) studios where (presumably) female tourists can pay to be made up and dressed to look like a maiko (apprentice geisha).

What options are available for men in Kyoto? Are there any commonly available options apart from dressing up as a samurai?

Studio shoot versus going outdoors isn't a major consideration - either's fine.

Comment: I'm confused about what the question is exactly. Can you provide some link or some further explanation? Where do "samurais" come in to this?

Comment: 1. Studio? Are you meaning a costume rental place, photo studio or a TV / Film Set?
2. As far as I am aware, no geishas are male unless they are cross-dressing however this is far from the norm.
3. There is no such word as "samurais" (the singular and plural are both samurai).
4. Popular options will be classed as opinion based for the most part, however a large majority of what people can be seen dressing up in in Kyoto are things like Kimono (both male and female, usually in Autumn / Winter / Spring) or Yukata / Jinbei (Summer).

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder I've updated the question to answer question 1.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm I assume you mean something like this? http://www.maiko-henshin.com/en

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder yes. If there's a more correct English expression than "maiko henshin studio", let me know.

Comment: That website is a photo studio specialising in Maiko / Geisha - style photographs. You will notice the most time you can walk around freely on any plan is 20 mins. From what I have seen, male options are somewhat limited to what you refer to as "Samurai" style as found for example here http://www.kyoto-maiko.com/English/. You also haven't specified if you are looking just for photos or if you intend to walk around. The available options change considerably between the two. If you are just looking to hire the Kimono / Yukata, then there are standard Kimono / Yukata options for males.

Comment: This site may offer you some hints. https://www.tsunagujapan.com/10-places-in-kyoto-to-play-dress-up-in-traditional-kimono/

Comment: Not sure if this is something that would be of interest- but there are some tours that involve dressing as a ninja and either poking about in the outdoors or in an urban setting. Pretty silly but it might be memorable.

Comment: Is the question more clear now?

Comment: Have you thought about just doing the geisha makeover? :)

Comment: Could you give more clarification as to what you are looking for exactly? Possibly add pictures? Right now it's hard to tell... Do you want a simple clothes renting shop or a more complete experience with a photograph?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you go to Toho Uzumasa Eigamura in Kyoto, you can dress like a ninja along with other samurai, royalty, and townsperson variations. There are even European royalty (as imagined by shojo manga) variations.

[image: Toho Eigamura]

http://www.toei-eigamura.com/event/detail/53

After you get dressed up, they take your photo in the shop and then you can walk around the theme park, which is the actual movie sets for Toho Studios for their jidaigeki (Tokugawa/samurai) films.

I linked to the Japanese site above as it has photos of the costumes available, which the English site doesn't.

Note: there's an entry fee to the theme park in addition to the costume and makeup fee.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with the term, shojo manga means manga aimed at teen girls. http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/22823/english-english-term-for-shōjo-manga

Comment: Kinda sad I didn't get more clarifications, but you did get accepted, so bounty for you!

Comment: Happy to add anything if you want further clarification. Thanks for the bounty too!

Answer (score 4):

It seems that many of the kimono rental shops that cater to women also carry men's kimono.

For example:

[Okamoto Kimono](http://okamoto-kimono.com/english/kimono/plan_mens/index.html) offers large selection of kimono including formal, long-sleeved or hakama for rental.
[image][image]

[Kyoto Kimono Rental](https://kyotokimono-rental.com/en/kimono/men-kimono) and [Yumeyakata](http://www.yumeyakata.com/english/plan.html) also offer similar plans.

There are other shops that may fit your needs better, I encourage you to search online.

---

*Note: I am not affiliated with any of these sites, nor have I ever used their service. Make sure to contact them to make sure that the service is in fact available.*