# Where to find vintage electronics in Tokyo?

Tags: japan, electronic-items, shopping, tokyo

I'm really into vintage audio equipment. Where/if in Tokyo might one find second-hand, high-end, Sony, Denon, Technics, Pioneer, Nakamichi stereo components of 70s/80s/90s vintage in excellent condition?

Comment: Hi echobase, welcome to Travel.SE. This question is likely to be considered off-topic here, for more information see http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/241/what-is-a-shopping-question

Comment: @TimMalone Personally, I don't think it's necessarily off-topic as the asker isn't asking what to buy, but instead where he could find something.  For example, Andrew Grimm asked something similar a while back and it wasn't flagged as off-topic. (http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74212/male-alternatives-to-dressing-up-as-a-geisha-in-kyoto)

Comment: @JSLavertu I was going by the 'If a local might have the same question, then it's not a travel-related question' guidance in that meta post. But, I'm not a close-voter, so others with more experience here will decide :)

Comment: @TimMalone Yeah, I agree it's kinda on the line... We'll see what happens.

Comment: Same wish.. did you find those shops in akihabara? I'd love to buy some vintage stuff.. tape deck or nissan Cedric streteo from 1984 ..
Been to akihabara today but didn't find :.(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While this is likely to be off topic, here's an answer:

### [**Akihabara**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akihabara)

This is **THE** spot for buying vintage electronics.

[image]

While it seems from the outside that Akihabara is only anime and manga everywhere, originally the area was (and still is) the best spot for electronics.

You want to visit the maze of small shops under the tracks of the Sobu main line. [This image shows where you can find the many entrances.](https://www.google.ca/maps/@35.698671,139.7713228,3a,75y,137.39h,90.3t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sE5M1U1fb8EScm7so44a2XQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656!6m1!1e1)

Keep in mind that there are many other shops around Akihabara, it would be too long to catalog them all, but I encourage you to explore around.

Answer (score 2):

While Akihabara is the "place to be" for this kind of stuff, there are other places for this. One good example is Nakano Broadway. You also might find what you are looking for in stores like hard off and book off, which you can find about everywhere in Tokyo (and Japan). Also, roaming around Shinjuku, you will find plenty of vintage electronics shops.